# How to check if a Django arrayfield has data

Tags: django

I have a Django model for articles with an array field that sometimes has ids.

```
id_list = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=10000), blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to write a query that finds all the article objects that have data in the id_list. I tried the following, but it did not work.

```
Article.objects.filter(id_list__isnull=False)
```

What is the correct way to write this? Thank you.

Comment: you can use len

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the [`len`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#len) filter on an `ArrayField` and filter where the length of the array is greater than 0

```
Article.objects.filter(id_list__len__gt=0)
```